# JHipster default test cases failing

Tags: unit-testing, jhipster

I've created application using JHipster, it has default test cases which compares with its default values declared in variable.
Ex.

```
private static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "AAAAAAAAAA";
private static final String UPDATED_NAME = "BBBBBBBBBB";
```

Now, what I understand from console log is since application has data populated and  when default test cases gets response, its actual application/custom data which does not matches with the expected data.

Ex. 
without data population, `DEFAULT_NAME(AAAAAAAAAA)` matches with `UPDATED_NAME(BBBBBBBBBB)` but now since data is there, `DEFAULT_NAME(AAAAAAAAAA)` not matches with `UPDATED_NAME(INDIA)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you customized the logic in your application (such as the entity service or resource files), you will need to update the tests to test that logic.  For example, you force the `name` to `INDIA` in the code, then update the tests to check that instead of `BBBBBBBBBB`

Comment: Ok, but since we continuously updates entities so every time Test file will override, and also entities are in large number, this seem difficult to achieve as per our project structure. Is this only way?

Comment: Yes that is the only way, when you regenerate use a versioning tool to reapply your changes. Use the JHipster upgrade command when upgrading